# Re-binning python array

Tags: python, arrays, binning

Let's say I have arrays

```py
x=[0,0.5,1.7,4,5.5,5.7,8,10]
y=[10,23,2,3,55,67,74,20]
```

When plotted, it will show values 0 to 10 on the x-axis, however, the data is not binned to integer values on x. Is there a way we can bin values to x=[0,1,2,3....10].
I know interpolation can help us bin the values, any other method?

Comment: `x = list(range(len(y)))`

Comment: and what about the corresponding y values?

Comment: You did not show how you are plotting the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy can help.

```py
import numpy as np
x=[0,0.5,1.7,4,5.5,5.7,8,10]
y=[10,23,2,3,55,67,74,20]

z = np.interp([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], x, y)
```

z = array([10,14.25,2.13043478,2.56521739,3,37.66666667,14.86956522,44.43478261,74,47,20])

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This example interpolation with using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x=[0,0.5,1.7,4,5.5,5.7,8,10]
    y=[10,23,2,3,55,67,74,20]

    z = np.interp([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], x, y)

    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.plot(z)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

the result will show in this picture. The blue line is of coordinate x and y. The yellow is interploation